# Where to put testNG xml file in ANT java web project

Tags: java, testing, web, testng, testng-eclipse

I am using testNG in a java web project. When I run the test with gui eclipse on Linux machine it creates a .xml file in my /tmp/ folder. My concern is If I create a custom xml file then where to put that file in project and how we can run that test with eclipse gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your testng xml file under your project on the workspace.
and you can run it simply by right clicking on it, then select "Run as -> TestNG Test", please see more in the official doc: http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-create-method

Comment: I tried the same as You suggest but It is still creating a .xml file in /tmp folder.

Comment: well, I don't think in this case (running with an existing testng xml suite) will create new tmp xml suite file, what do you see on your console stdout? for example, here is my output: `[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/nick/Documents/workspace/mymixed/testng.xml`

Comment: No it is
      [TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse-1388025148/testng-customsuite.xml

Comment: ok, which testng eclipse version you're using? if it's not the latest (6.9.11), could you update and have a try again?

Comment: I am using TestNG Version 6.9.11.201604020423

Comment: ok then, i created a ticket for tracking this: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/259, could you share a small sample project for reproducing this issue if possible, thanks

Comment: I am not very familiar with git, but find the sample project in zip file from the following git link. https://github.com/sbmc7/testng.git

Answer (score 1):

I tried so many things to figure out the solution of the problem and finally got with the help of **@XuQing Tan**.

You can put your .xml suite file anywhere in the project.

There are two things **"Run as -> TestNG Test"** and **"Run as -> TestNG Suite"**

**"Run as -> TestNG Test"** requires a Class annotated with @Test and it will create a temporary .xml suite file.

**"Run as -> TestNG Suite"** requires a .xml suite file which you want to ask in the question.

If you right click in the middle of editor of .xml file, It may not show the **"Run as -> TestNG Suite"** option. For that you need to right click on file in Project Explorer and it will give you option **"Run as -> TestNG Suite"**.

You can also configure it by **Run Configurations...**

[image: Run Configurations Window]